# Load a LaTex template in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I have found this [LaTex template](https://github.com/rschuetzler/latex-icis-template) on GitHub that I would like to use in RMarkdown.

This is what I have in the YAML so far:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
    keep_tex: true
    fig_caption: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
title: "A title"
author:
- name: Name
  affiliation: University 
- name: Name
  affiliation: University
abstract: "Our research aims at..."
keywords: "r markdown, knitr"
cls: icisfinal.cls
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-style: apsr
---

Some text.
```

[image]
But it doesn't seem to work since I would expect the text to be in Georgia by default. How can I load the template and use it to format `Some text.` in Goergia?

Comment: Are the three requirements met? Document MUST be compiled with XeLaTeX in order to support the Georgia font family. You must have the Georgia font installed on the compiling computer. You must have the Biber software installed (automatically done for MiKTeX).

Comment: @Anonymouscoward  I have MikTeX installed, I've set `latex_engine: xelatex` and I assume Georgia is installed because I can call it using `mainfont: Georgia`

Comment: You could try `documentclass: icisfinal` instead of the cls call. Does everything else in the template appear to work?